# Twitter OAuth api on iphone 3.0?

Tags: iphone, twitter

I am using the demo code from

https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

When i build the demo code on iphone 3.0 it gives the 18 errors
[image]

It works on iphone 4.0

How can i solve these errors on iphone 3.0.??

Answer (score 0):

The latest library requires SDK 3.2 or greater. In order to run on 3.0 you need to collect an older version.

Comment: When you implement twitter outh then help i have to implement facebook and twitter both in my app

Comment: i have searched but i cannot find the older version..if you have please post the link..

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Im not 100% sure whether this will work or not. Try downloading this tree: https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone/tree/8573f69120faf9399d0c7c4ff66de19cf63fc57f

Comment: no... it does not work for me...any other solution for 3.0..??
Why this does not work on 3.0 ..any framework issue or what..?